# References: north-eastern Mandarin: xier meaning 'great/awesome/excellent'

Tags: word, topolect

Looking for any references here:

North-eastern Mandarin has the word `xier` (perhaps: `xuer`) usage is same as:

> 太棒了

i.e.: `太xier了`

As usual everyone thinks that it cannot be written & that there is no character for it.

So please any references to this word / character are requested.

edit: I did come across this:

> 血，读作 xie3，非常、十分的意思，与胶东东部方言对应词汇的发音、含义完全相同

on wikipedia - perhaps it is 太血儿了.

Comment: Would you like to give me the concrete context in which this xier is used?

Comment: I'm looking for - a dictionary entry - written usage - some sort of concrete reference to this word from `paper`.

Comment: I am from north-eastern, xier is not used in all north-eastern, only some area, ex. 大连, maybe some areas in 吉林 and 黑龙江 also use it.

Comment: @wolfrevo any idea how to write it?

Comment: Just 血, no 儿. It is very rare in writings even for these used in talking. btw, there is another character, 尿(means fantastic, brave), I don't know why there are many wild word in daily use.  It is not a good idea for me to use these character this way.

Comment: @wolfrevo 血 means awesome?

Comment: @user3306356 means super, very,  it just reminds me that 尿, I think those are same kinds of word. Forget it.

Answer (score 2):

Could the word be 玄 （xuán)? In Beijing, it means "improbable" or "unbelievable", "out there". If spoken with a Beijing "er" attached, it sounds like xuán-er.

Answer (score 1):

I asked a friend who is from NE China (一位来自沈阳人) about 太xie了 and they came up with this: 太邪了 (tai4xie2le5).

邪 means "demonic, nefarious" but in 太邪了 I think it means "good" as in supernaturally, uncannily good (I think the English words "wonderful" and "fantastic" are related to this in some etymological/semantic manner). The friend didn't think 太血了 was correct.

Comment: That is because 沈阳人 do not use 血. So she/he confused with 邪.

Answer (score 0):

This use case of `血` does not apply to north-eastern mandarin, which is referred as `东北话`. It's in fact a word in `大连(Da Lian)话`. Dalian is a city in Liaoning Province, but `大连话` is really different from `东北话`. It's similar to the dialect of `胶东(Jiao Dong)`, which is a part of Shandong Province.

`血` here means very, not awesome. It's more an adverb than an adjective.

Example: `血彪`, which means `很傻`, is commonly used in `大连话`.

For more reference, you may search for `大连话` and ctrl+f for `血`.

Comment: So what in `大连(Da Lian)话` that sounds like `xier` means awesome then?

Comment: @user3306356 idk.

Comment: how about `shir`?

Comment: @user3306356 Nah.

Answer (score 0):

I think only 血(xie3), no postfix 儿(er).

血(xie3) in north-eastern China means 非常/很(very), and is always followed by an adjective (usually presents bad things).

血亏:  亏 means 亏损/损失(loss)
这趟生意真是血亏  a great loss in the business

In the next example, 血 means 十足的/尽全力的(plenty of, make best effort)

下血本:  下 means 投入(invest)，  本 means 本钱（capital, not always money）